# jQuery validate plugin & ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have a question regarding a form validation.
I'm using jQuery v1.10.2 & jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1 
and on submitting the form nothing happens. The form also gets the attribute novalidate="novalidate" which points out there's an error. 
The problem occurred when i added the submitHandler.
I just can't seem to find the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#modifySocial_form").validate({
        rules: {
            companyname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
        },
        messages: {
            companyname: "Please enter a correct company name"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var mydata = '{';
            mydata += '"name1": "' + document.getElementById('modify_name1').value + '", ';
            mydata += '"name2": "' + document.getElementById('modify_name2').value + '", ';
            mydata += '"address": "' + document.getElementById('modify_address').value + '", ';
            mydata += '}';
            //alert(mydata);
            var myurl = "{{ path('modify_social') }}";
            $.ajax({
                url: myurl,
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data: mydata,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.return_code == 'OK') {
                        document.getElementById('ajaxReturn').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success">Modification Successful</div>';
                        window.setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 500);
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('ajaxReturn').innerHTML = result.result;
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Big thanks if anyone can help me out!

Comment: `var myurl = "{{ path('modify_social') }}";` why are the double curly braces? what is `path`?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the trailing comma in this line:
    mydata += '"address": "' + document.getElementById('modify_address').value + '", ';

which becomes:
    mydata += '"address": "' + document.getElementById('modify_address').value + '"';